# What is the effect on shelter prices of raising interest rates?

Tags: inflation, interest-rate, monetary-policy, fed-funds-rate, rent

In the UK, a rise in rates causes a rise in mortgage repayments. It can lead to landlords raising rents due to margin pressure, if their mortgage is not fixed or is close to the end of its fixed period.

But also the tenants are now less able to afford to buy giving them little choice but to accept the new rent, and leading to greater demand for rental properties.

Of course, if rates increase significantly, home prices can drop enough to make them more affordable.

Let's turn to the US and particularly shelter within the CPI data. This brings into consideration the way the number is computed.

- Does a rising **federal funds rate** lead to rising rents?
- If you were on the **FOMC** and wanted to bring shelter costs down, would you raise or lower interest rates?

Shelter as computed by the US BLS:

https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2022/05/18/how-does-the-consumer-price-index-account-for-the-cost-of-housing/

This Tweet notes the differences in mortgage market structure between US and UK.

> Contrary to the US where rates can be fixed for 30Y, in UK mortgage rates are capped for initial 2/5Y then they are floating.

https://twitter.com/MenthorQpro/status/1576707769427988482?s=20&t=x1STEeIWdmgpcxl4WOa0kg

Comment: It's the official CPI definition of shelter, you want to bring it down ASAP as per CPI prints each month, and the rate is the fed funds rate.